# Figuring out TextFormatFlags

Tags: .net, vb.net, gdi+

I'm trying to use the TextRenderer (.NET v4.0) to display a paragraph of text on a custom control.  If the text is too big for the maximum space I've allowed, I want the text to be truncated and the ellipsis put on the end - but I can't figure out the right combination of TextFormatFlags to do it.
Excerpt of test code so far;

```
Using vPlotFont As New Font("Verdana", 7, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point)
  Dim vWidth = Me.Width - vTextLeft - Me.Margin.Right
  Dim vFlags = TextFormatFlags.Left Or TextFormatFlags.EndEllipsis Or TextFormatFlags.WordBreak
  Dim vRequiredHeight = TextRenderer.MeasureText(mvSummaryData, vPlotFont, New Size(vWidth, 1), vFlags).Height
  Dim vRectangle As New Rectangle(vTextLeft, 25, vWidth, Math.Min(vRequiredHeight, 40))  ' Restrict to 40 pixels maximum
  TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, mvSummaryData, vPlotFont, vRectangle, Color.Red, vFlags)
  e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, vRectangle)  ' For debugging/testing only
End Using
```

Because the height is restricted at 40, anything that doesn't fit is truncated - how do I tell it apply the trimming/ellipsis when it overflows?!

Comment: I figured it out - using the `Graphics.MeasureString` and `Graphics.DrawString`, along with a `StringFormat.Trimming.StringTrimming.EllipsisWord`! I can post the code if anyone's interested...
Is `TextRenderer` becoming obsolete now?  It doesn't seem to have changed since .NET 1.1?

Comment: Graphics.DrawString is no substitute for TextRenderer.  The snippet doesn't make much sense.  If the height is restricted to 40 then there just isn't any point in measuring the text.  Simply pass a rectangle of 40 high to DrawText

Comment: @HansPassant - the 40 was just to restrict the rectangle to something my text wouldn't fit into; to try and get the ellipsis to show up.
I can understand that `TextRenderer` has benefits over `DrawString`, but in this case, if I can't get the ellipsis to show up then I'd rather use `DrawString`!